Contours of the real part and complex part of a complex function
The question is the following: Consider the complex function $f(z)=1 / z$. Draw the contours $u=\operatorname{Re} f=$ constant and $v=\operatorname{Im} f=$ constant. How do they intersect? Is it always true that grad $u$ is parallel to the curve $v=$ constant?
I figured out that $u$ is a circle centered at $(1/(2c),0)$ with the radius of $1/(2c)$, and that $v$ is a circle centered at $(0,1/(2c))$ with the radius of $1/(2c)$. However, I am not sure that how grad $u$ is parallel to the curve $v=$ constant.
